# Overwriting variables after adding event listener

Tags: javascript

I was looking into [this awesome Three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/css3d_periodictable.html) and wanted to understand what was going on. At the end of the init function I noticed that there were 4 buttons being made and overwritten each time... At first I thought this was weird that it worked, because I've never thought of it like this... But I assume the eventlisteners are added to the HTML element and stay on there even though the reference `var button` gets overwritten?

Since I haven't seen this anywhere else, is this - in a very very small way - more performant because you use 3 less variables here? Just theoretically speaking here. Is this a recommended way of programming or rather not?

*The piece of code I'm referring to:*

```
        var button = document.getElementById( 'table' );
        button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

            transform( targets.table, 2000 );

        }, false );

        var button = document.getElementById( 'sphere' );
        button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

            transform( targets.sphere, 2000 );

        }, false );

        var button = document.getElementById( 'helix' );
        button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

            transform( targets.helix, 2000 );

        }, false );

        var button = document.getElementById( 'grid' );
        button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

            transform( targets.grid, 2000 );

        }, false );

        transform( targets.table, 2000 );
```

Comment: It *could* create smaller code depending on the engine implementation. As for whether it's recommended is going to come down to opinion. I think redeclaring a variable repeatedly is bad form. I also think in this case it would have been better for them to do `document.getElementById('selector').addEventListener(...` since they never reference `button` again.

Comment: Didn't even think of that yet. Indeed it would be better to use the method you're showing. I guess you could go further by using a forEach on the container of those buttons and then using the id of each element as the key for targets, but that might be a little overkill for just 4 buttons. Thanks!

Comment: You got it! Just for fun, [here's how I would write it.](https://pastebin.com/kPHRZJ0M)

Comment: Way more readable :)

Comment: Sidenote: This is a [similar example](http://graphoverflow.com/graphs/3d-periodic-table.html) by my friend using three.js itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript does [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) which means redeclaring the variable in same scope doesn't have any effect. It will be hoisted to have only one declaration at top of the `function` or current scope.

```
    var button = document.getElementById( 'table' );
    button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {

        transform( targets.table, 2000 );

    }, false );

    var button = document.getElementById( 'sphere' );
    button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {}, false );
```

will be rewritten as:

```
    var button;

    button = document.getElementById( 'table' );
    button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {}, false );

    button = document.getElementById( 'sphere' );
    button.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {}, false );
```

> I assume the eventlisteners are added to the HTML element and stay on
>   there even though the reference var button gets overwritten

That is right, overwriting a reference to a DOM Node won't delete the DOM node anyway nor affect any event listeners.

> Since I haven't seen this anywhere else, is this - in a very very
>   small way - more performant because you use 3 less variables here?

3 less variable doesn't give much of a performance boost I guess. Re-assigning same variable another value of a different type can even be expensive at times when using optimising compiler.

> Just theoretically speaking here. Is this a recommended way of
>   programming or rather not?

I don't think so, it is better to have clearly named different variable names for different buttons so that the code is more readable.

Comment: I didn't know re-assigning could be more expensive. Do you have any example where this is the case?

Comment: Check [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/#toc-topic-hiddenclasses) As mentioned it happens usually when the type changes.

Answer (score 0):

The `addEventListener` is added to the element independently of the variable, in this case you are creating a variable that already exists. Not bad but in the code is declared a variable that is no longer used.

*This may be done otherwise as below*

```
var button = document.getElementById('table');
button.addEventListener( 'click'...
button = document.getElementById( 'sphere' );
button.addEventListener( 'click'...
```

*However the variable is not used more so as below it would be better*

```
document.getElementById('table').addEventListener( 'click'...
document.getElementById( 'sphere' ).addEventListener( 'click'...
```